# How can I give access to my current terminal output to other users?

Tags: bash, debian, scripting

I am given a task to create a bash script that would act like a `wall` command, but users' messages must be directed to my current terminal only. I have got the following code written so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter your message: " msg
target_tty=`who | egrep "1910901" | cut -d' ' -f3`
echo $msg > "/dev/$target_tty"
```

I have set the access modifiers for the script file like so: `-rws-r-xr-x`, but I get `Permisson denied` error anyway. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`write` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/write.1.html)?
You'll have to make the receiving terminal accept incoming writes with `mesg y`

Comment: My immediate thought is the 'permission denied' error is not about the script's permissions itself, but telling you that you do not have permission to write to "/dev/$target_tty". This is to prevent multi-user systems from spamming and harassing each other. (Imagine if you had an account on some server, and some advertiser also made an account then constantly spammed "Buy my products!" to every single user logged in to the system, and you can see why this is so.)

Comment: @Christo, well, I checked the command and the problem is that I have to write my own version of it from scratch. This is an extra task for my assignment.